# Unable to get token in Recharge { error: 'unsupported_grant_type' }

Tags: javascript, api

```
    const axios = require("axios");
    const BASE_URL = `https://www.admin.rechargeapps.com/oauth/token`
    var params = {
     code: "0xDEADBEEF",
     grant_type: "authorization_code",
     redirect_uri: "https://your_domain.com",
     client_id: "*********************"
   }
   let body = JSON.stringify(params)
   getCompatibility = () => axios({
     method: "POST",
     url: BASE_URL,
     data: body,
     headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },

    })
```

I tried this to get token from recharge but all am getting is data: { error: 'unsupported_grant_type' } is there anything I have missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just need to change grant_type with "client_credentials":-

```js
  const axios = require("axios");
    const BASE_URL = `https://www.admin.rechargeapps.com/oauth/token`
    var params = {
     code: "0xDEADBEEF",
     grant_type: "client_credentials",
     redirect_uri: "https://your_domain.com",
     client_id: "*********************"
   }
   let body = JSON.stringify(params)
   getCompatibility = () => axios({
     method: "POST",
     url: BASE_URL,
     data: body,
     headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },

    })
)
```

Thanks !

Comment: I did that but it is not working